# WinXP - Map network location to local folder

Tags: windows-xp, symbolic-link, networking, junction

I have a network location, `\\myserver\myshare`. On my Windows XP box, I wish to map this location to the path `c:\somefolder`. Am I asking the impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is I asked the impossible. There's no way to do what I wanted.

Comment: Other answers cited the fact that this basically isn't possible. Give credit where it's due.

Comment: @Chris No, other answers gave _alternate solutions_. Nobody but me actually said that what I wanted was not possible.

Answer (score 6):

Are you sure this is really what you want to do? There's a very good article on why this is a ***bad bad bad*** idea [over at Joel on Software](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000041.html) (see point #3)...

> Conclusion: the next time someone
>   tries to sell you a programming
>   product that lets you access network
>   resources the same was as you access
>   local resources, run full speed in the
>   opposite direction.

If you want to know why, read the relevant parts of the article.

Comment: Joel is right in point 3 that making slow network resources appear local may break user expectations and point 1 that correct search results are better than lots of search results. He's wrong in his point 2 diatribe against antialiasing.

Comment: Haha, well that article is actually 9 years old now. He posted another follow-up to state that anti-aliasing was greatly improved in XP

Comment: Sometimes, you don't really have a choice - usually, due to application restrictions (eg, MUST be located in a particular folder to work, but you can't actually put it there due to company policy/etc.) That's where I'm sitting right now.  Working slowly is always faster than not working at all!

Answer (score 2):

You are asking the impossible :)

You need a NTFS symbolic link for what you want.

Unlike an NTFS junction point (available since Windows 2000), a symbolic link can also point to a file or remote SMB network path.

SMB2 is required for symbolic links in windows, which is written into the vista/win7 network stacks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the way you're intending. Windows handles symlinks as a physical descriptor. The tool to create them is "linkd" on WinXP. It requires a local filesystem formated for NTFS as a target.

The closest Windows gets is through DFS. In that case you're creating a special share on a server that your workstation maps to. That share then has its own assembled name-space that's probably what you're looking for. It isn't local, though.

Answer (score 1):

On Vista (and later) you can create a symbolic link with mklink.

Comment: Thanks, but I need this on a Windows XP box.

Comment: Prior to Vista you should be able to make use of sysinternals junction.exe.

Comment: @Brian Junctions don't do what I want.

Answer (score -1):

I havent tried this...and I am not exactly sure what you are talking about, but could you start off with \\127.0.0.1

THis is just a guess.

Comment: reading over this answer almost a year later I have no idea what i was thinking.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too sure if this is what you're after, but windows XP can Map Network Drive/Network Folder into a drive (Z:\ etc) but not to a specific folder.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but if you have a software that requires access to their files in a local-looking drive, you can do a Map-Network Drive and that should do it for you. (But please take note of Farseeker's answer and the link provided).

If you simply need a way to access your network drive easily, create a Shortcut directly to the Network Drive (or map the network drive).