# True virtual hard drive (using drivers)

Tags: windows, virtualization, hard-drive

We have a legacy application that can only read and write to physical drives. If we point it to a mapped network drive, it does not work. I've tried `subst`, `mklink` and `net use` to no avail.

Is there a program that can create a virtual hard drive on Windows 10 (using drivers)? Then, allow me to specify where this virtual drive should get its data from? In this case, a networked drive.

Edit: [iSCSI Target](https://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/iscsi-target) by Daemon came pretty close, but can't seem to provide an iSCSI target that is backed by a network drive.

Edit 2: [This question](https://serverfault.com/questions/108193/mount-network-drive-as-physical-drive) proses the question in a different way. It contains useful information.

Edit 3: Haha, oh no. [THE](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/22/three-wrong-ideas-from-computer-science/) man himself suggests it's a bad idea:

> The next time someone tries to sell you a programming product that
>   lets you access network resources the same was as you access local
>   resources, run full speed in the opposite direction.

Comment: google the term iscsi

Comment: Thanks Zore. iSCSI comes pretty close to solving the problem. The networked drive that I'm referring to can't be an iSCSI target - it's just a normal SMB network share.

Comment: What Operating system is the network share running on?

Comment: Hi Michael, it's running Windows 10. I could run iSCSI target on it, however it only exposes Physical or Virtual (VHD) devices, not just a specific folder.

Comment: Why does it have to be just a normal SMB share?

Comment: How about mounting a VHDX from a remote share?  You can mount it to a local path, or local drive letter. You'll need to deal with reboots, however.

Comment: mklink worked for me a old era-DOS program, AppV maybe for your case ? (https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/mdop/appv-v5/performance-guidance-for-application-virtualization-50#BKMK_US)

Answer (score 6):

Why doesn't the Daemon target with SPTI/SPTD fit in your case?

As an alternative you can take a look at [StarWind Free](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free) for example, in this case you just need to create new device on top of your smb drive and share it through iSCSI.

Comment: iSCSI on top of SMB is an extra complexity. IMHO.